# what is difference between ansible and ansible-galaxy

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

just wanted to understand what is the core difference between ansible and ansible-galaxy ?
from docs, ansible-galaxy is to manage roles (create and publish)
then what is the ansible is for ? to run just playbooks ?

cant we create rols using ansible command line ?

Regards,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ansible Galaxy is a repository for ansible roles. It's what PyPI is to Python, or what Maven is to Java. `ansible-galaxy` is a tool that retrieves roles from Ansible Galaxy and installs them. Same thing roughly as `pip` is to Python.